# Ionic1 Factory $http request returning promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a ionic1 application which works with my API endpoints.

I've created a service which on call gets categories.

```
.factory('expenses', function($http) {

    var expenseCategories = [];

    return {

        getCategories: function(){

            return $http.get('URL_HERE').then(function(response){
                expenseCategories = response.data.data[0];
                return expenseCategories.categories;
            });

        }

    }

})
```

I call the service in my controller

```
.controller('expenseCategoryCtrl', function($scope, $state, expenses) {

  $scope.categories = expenses;
  $scope.data = $scope.categories.getCategories();
  console.log($scope.data);

})
```

When console logging the response it returns a promise rather than my usual json from the API. If I call the API in the controller I can ng-repeat the collection with no issues however now it's in a service it's wrapped in this "promise" and I'm unsure how to output the collection.

[image: Screenshot of Console Log]

I've tried

```
<li class="item item-toggle" ng-repeat="categories as category">
         {{ category }}
      </li>
```

but I get the error

> [ngRepeat:iexp] Expected expression in form of '*item* in
>   *collection*[ track by *id*]' but got 'categories as category'.

I believe this is a case of not understanding the promise.

Answer (score 1):

hope this will work:

```
.controller('expenseCategoryCtrl', function($scope, $state, expenses) {

  $scope.categories = expenses;
  $scope.data = $scope.categories.getCategories().then(function(response){
console.log(response);
},function(error){
console.log(error);
});
  console.log($scope.data);

})
```

Comment: `console.log(response)` should console the output you want.

Answer (score 0):

Async operation doesn't work the way you're thinking. You will get data when promise accomplished. So on `getCategories` method you could put `.then` function and it will call `successFn` one promise fulfilled otherwise on error it calls `errorFn`.

```
$scope.categories.getCategories().then(function successFn(data){
  $scope.data = data
}, function errorFn(error){ console.log(error) });
```

---

In console what you were getting was promise object returned by `$http` service as you directly assigned promise to `$scope.data`.